# how to get the delta from neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, timedelta, delta

I am uing neo4j DB. i don't know how to identify the properties or attribuites in a node or relation in neo4j, that gets changed over a period of time, assuming there are no timestamps. please suggest a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as far as I know there is nothing by default that would give the insert / update time. You should add additional properties on your nodes and relationships to track the insert / update time. You can't use date data type, so you'll have to convert them to strings.

Comment: I think you're right, there is no built-in functionality for that. It may be better to store dates typed as `long` than `String` however, since you can then use math operators and functions. Also, the `timestamp()` function can be useful, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-timestamp